# If I have a multidimentional array, how can I acsess only the first value of the first dimention?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5.5

If I have a multidimentional array, how can I acsess only the first value of the first dimention. I will Explain:

```
sampleArray=new Array[];

sampleArray[0]=["Nouns","Adjectives","Verbs"];
sampleArray[1]=["Colors","Time","Sound];
sampleArray[0][0]=["Person","Place","Thing"]
```

I would just like to get the word `Nouns` but when I try to get the value of`sampleArray[0][0]` it will just result `Person, Place, Thing`!

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked with flash, but what you're doing looks ok to me. Have you tried doing it in two steps: i.e. `valArr = sampleArray[0]; val = valArrr[0];`

Comment: Also, I recognize that this is probably oversimplified code, but have you considered creating a class to handle at least some of this? 2d arrays have a bit of a smell to them except for a handfull of certain cases (which your test code doesn't look like it falls under).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code "Nouns" is actually located at

```
sampleArray[0][0]
```

However you are replacing that with

```
sampleArray[0][0]=["Person","Place","Thing"]
```

Perhaps it would be easier to keep your information in an object. Then reference them that way. Not sure what your end goal is though so that may not work for you.

```
var partsOfSpeach = {};
var noun = {};
noun.name = "Noun";
noun.def = ["Person","Place","Thing"];
partsOfSpeach.Noun = noun;
```

Then you can access the info at

```
trace(partsOfSpeach.Noun.name); // "Noun"
trace(partsOfSpeach.Noun.def); // "Person","Place","Thing"
```